# "CSS module is undefined" error when using react-css-modules with react-router with locale and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm using react with react-router and CSS-modules and webpack. This was all working nicely, but now a requirement has come in to be able to change language. I first tried to do this by only changing a state attribute to the different language, but when changing it the current route doesn't rerender, so the language change would only take effect when the next route change happens, i.e click on a link.

Plan B: trying to add the locale to the routing / so it appears in the URL now, which should then take effect because route update -> rerender. However I am getting errors when loading my CSS modules now.

This is my router setup:

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRedirect to="/english/hydraulics" />
      <Route path="/:lang">
        <IndexRedirect to="/hydraulics" />
        <Route path="/" component={Hydraulics}/>
        <Route path="hydraulics" component={Hydraulics}/>
        <Route path="bearings" component={Bearings}/>
        <Route path="compressor" component={Compressor}/>
        <Route path="gears" component={Gears}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

This is my functions in my app:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._updateLanguage = this._updateLanguage.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      lang: 'english',
      language: english
    })
  }

  _updateLanguage(language) {
    this.setState({
      language: language === ENGLISH ? english : russian
    });
  }

  _addChildren() {
    return this.props.children ? React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {language: this.state.language}) : this.props.children;
  }

  render() {

    var language = this.state.language;
    var children = this.props.children;

    return <div className={wrapper}>
        <Nav copy={this.state.language} location={this.props.location} callback={this._updateLanguage} locale={this.state.lang}/>
        <section className={content}>
          { this._addChildren() }
        </section>
      </div>
  }
```

My default route is hydraulics, so am getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: "is-english/hydraulics" CSS module is undefined.

I wonder if it is a configuration in my webpack css modules loader:

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
      },
```

in the hydraulics.jsx I am importing the CSS like this:

```
import styles from './hydraulics.css';
```

what I don't understand is why the css modules are loaded from "is-english", where is that "is-" prefix coming from? Also the file isn't in an english subfolder, it's just in the same folder as hydraulics.jsx

Or whether it's got something to do with the way the routes have been arranged?